# TypeScript. How can I declare a DOM Collection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have tried:

```
let $inputsCollection:HTMLCollection = document.body.querySelectorAll('input');

let $inputsCollection:HTMLCollection = document.body.querySelectorAll('input') as HTMLCollection;

let $inputsCollection = document.body.querySelectorAll('input') as HTMLCollection;
```

I have tried several ways, but none work.

Comment: ¿Have you tried `let $inputsCollection: HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) does not return an `HTMLCollection` but a `NodeList`. There's no point trying to convert the `NodeList` to an `HTMLCollection`. You can do this though:

```
let $inputsCollection: NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement> = 
  document.body.querySelectorAll('input');
```

The case above uses `HTMLInputElement` so all elements in the list have to be from `input` elements in the HTML. For cases where you'll get heterogeneous elements out of the query, you can do:

```
let $inputsCollection: NodeListOf<Element> = 
  document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
```

This would even allow other types of nodes than `Element` objects, though `querySelectorAll` cannot return such nodes:

```
let $inputsCollection2: NodeList = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
```

FYI, the methods that return `HTMLCollection` objects are the `.getElementsBy...` family of methods (`.getElementsByClassName`, `.getElementsByTagName`, etc.)